# Dynamically creating asp.net with c# pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am struggling with finding clear answers to dynamically creating the same page over and over.  The questions and samples I have found seem to be all over the board on this topic.  I have studied the life cycle and still seem to not have a clear answer as to where code should go.

I have a master page and a content page.  All the content in the content area needs to be dynamically created (text boxes, ddl's, page tabs, buttons/onclick etc.).

After a user fills in data and clicks a submit button, I need to read the values off the form and rebuild the page completely again (not add/remove controls to current content).

My question is then.
Where do I put my code to build the page?
Will this area allow me to use IsPostBack so I can rebuild content with Request.Form values?
Will my buttons _Click events work?
Are there any working samples out there you could direct me to?

Thank you very much for the feedback...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know all the answers to your questions, but I hope this may get you started.  When dynamically generating the UI through code, this happens in Init.  Controls dynamically loaded on Init is key because between init and load, on postback, viewstate is loaded for these controls.

This means you need, on every postback, recreate the page as is to match the previous control tree, then deconstruct it after init and recreate the new UI, if something is supposed to change UI wise.  This is because it validates the tree structure to determine its the same UI.  Now, if you don't need viewstate, this may not be as much of an issue.  I haven't verified this without viewstate to see if it behaves different.

It depends how dynamic you need it, whether you need viewstate (is a big factor).

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the controls in the page's PreInit method.  "IsPostBack" should work and the click event handlers should work as well.

Comment: PreInit is the way to go here. The controls will the restored in the OnInit Event and properties will be assigned to the controls, but only if the have the same name

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a web user control, see [ASP.NET User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Brian's advices are good and you should follow them.

This might not really answer your question but still I add it as an advice. I'm professionally creating ASP.net web applications at quite a large scale and from my experience I can say that too much "dynamics" is usually bad and should be avoided because it just introduces complexity. Normally you might want to expose UI parts into ASP.net UserControls or if you want to make them even more reusable (if that's a factor) then into ASP.net Server controls. Then you replace different of them dynamically rather than creating everything from scratch.